# Sorting a collection of songs by runtime

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have to make a program that sorts a collection of songs by runtime. I have to analyse a selection of songs, each with a "Title" string, a "Composer" string, and a "Running Time" integer. Input will be piped through stdin, and output will be in stdout.

Here's an example input:

```
3
&
Pink Frost&Phillipps, Martin&234933
Se quel guerrier io fossi&Puccini, Giacomo&297539
Non piu andrai&Mozart&234933
M'appari tutt'amor&Flotow, F&252905
```

And output:

```
Se quel guerrier io fossi&Puccini, Giacomo&297539
M'appari tutt'amor&Flotow, F&252905
Non piu andrai&Mozart&234933
```

I know I have to sort these by Running Time, but I'm not sure which sorting algorithm to use. By general knowledge, the two sorting algo's that come to mind are Merge Sort and Quicksort, because they seem to be the quickest on average. I also have the idea of using a Comparator to compare two "Running time" elements in a Collection.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: by the way - String class has `compareTo(String s)` method, Integer class should have it too, but u shouldn't use it, ever. In most cases you just need **primitive** `int` type. So comparing `int`s is just simple as `return firstInt - secondInt;` to be more precise... this is what you need `public class TitleComparator implements Comparator<MySong> {

 @Override
 public int compare(MySong firstSong, MySong second) {
  return firstSong.getTitle() - second.getTitle();
 }

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stick to `compareTo()` method for String or int (running tittle) and use them in your `Comparator`s. Nextly - use `Collections.sort()` which uses merge sort that is quite good :)

Ah and during runtime you should add those songs to list of songs - `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`. And sort them by `Collections.sort(yourListName, new yourComparatorName());`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to write a class to hold the above values, which implements Comparable interface (or you could write up your own Comparator). The compareTo method can check the runtime and return a value accordingly.

Then pass it up to Collections.sort() method. This method uses a optimized version of Merge Sort. You don't have to write your own sorting logic to handle it this way, and you can rely on the Java Platform to do it for you. Unless you need specific performance tuning of sorting method, I guess this is the simplest way to go (KISS - Keep It Simple, Stupid).

Excerpt from Java API Docs on Collections.sort (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29):

> The sorting algorithm is a modified mergesort (in which the merge is omitted if the highest element in the low sublist is less than the lowest element in the high sublist). This algorithm offers guaranteed n log(n) performance. This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array. This avoids the n2 log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in place.